# Spring event/notification on application loading failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a way in Spring to be notified when application startup ends with failure (due to the missing bean, missing property, invalid configuration, etc...).
I would like to be able to notify other parts of the stack (namely Jenkins server) that the application has failed to deploy correctly.
I've noticed that ...

```
SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(ConfigurableApplicationContext context,
            SpringApplicationRunListeners listeners, Throwable exception)
```

...is called if the app failed to start. I also noticed that the method

```
private int getExitCodeFromException(ConfigurableApplicationContext context,
            Throwable exception)
```

is invoked during context shutdown/error handling, so I tried to register bean of type *ExitCodeExceptionMapper*, but the defined beans' method is never called because the target error (the one which I want to be notified of) occurred before the bean is loaded.

The application is deployed on Tomcat and started via *SpringBootServletInitializer*.

Is there another way to catch context startup failure error in Spring Boot application?

Comment: The bean that you registered, did you try adding @Configration annotation on it? so it will be loaded first

Comment: If you mean like this:
`@Configuration
public class ExitCodeConfiguration{
 @Bean
 public ExitCodeExceptionMapper exitCodeExceptionMapper() {
  return exception -> {
   return 1;
  };
 }
}`

Error is thrown before this configuration is initialized....